# Node js сервер ребут при обновлении сайта

Tags: node.js

Есть запущенный сервер на ноде. На сервер постоянно идут данные. Сейчас он работает с помощью модуля forever. При заливании измененных файлов я в консоли SSH вызываю команду

```
git pull
```

и перезапускаю сервер

```
forever stop bin/www
```

при этом сервер не работает некоторое время и поступающие данные не записываются.
Как заливать файлы не перезапуская сервер. Какой нужно юзать плагин.

Comment: Zero downtime deployment, м-м... Приключееения!

Comment: А поподробней!!

Comment: Я неделю назад дал вам ответ про это :)

Comment: Дел много, только дошел до этого. Перелопатил весь интернет, но так и не разобрался. Пробовал pm2 прикрутить, но какой то он мудреный.

Answer (score 2):

### У вас два варианта.

---

Либо вы делаете "честное [**сине-зелёное разворачивание**"](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/BlueGreenDeployment.html), для которого сами запросы должны поступать на **балансировщик нагрузки**, а уже с него уходить на **сервер приложения**, активный в данный момент. В этом случае для перезапуска без простоя вам нужно будет:

- Поднять процесс с новой версией
- Дождаться, пока он запустится и проверить, что он будет работать корректно

  - Чтобы автоматизировать процесс, стоит сделать на сервере отдельный метод, проверяющий, всё ли есть для работы: соединение с БД, кэш-сервер, учётные данные, или что вы ещё там используете...
  - Есть смысл сделать метод, отдающий текущую версию.
- Переключить **балансировщик** на новую версию, чтобы все новые запросы шли на неё

  - Тут зависит от того, каким балансировщиком вы будете пользоваться. Я обычно в этой роли вижу `nginx` и HAProxy, ещё слышал про Varnish.
- Убедиться, что всё работает

  - К примеру, с внешней машины спросить у системы её версию, убедиться, что это уже новая.
- Отдать процессу со старой версией команду "потихоньку выключаться" (graceful stop)

  - ...не разрывая соединений с клиентами, а дождавшись, пока они *всё доделают* в обслуживаемых запросах. Новых запросов туда всё равно поступать уже не будет.

---

Либо вы усложняете архитектуру системы, **делая простой отдельных элементов допустимым**.

Разделите **приём** данных и **обработку**. А между ними заведите *буфер*.

Пусть данные будет собирать какая-нибудь очередь, например [RabbitMQ](https://www.rabbitmq.com/), а обработчик(-и?) будут затягивать данные из неё.

RabbitMQ также может раздавать сообщения, не удаляя их у себя, пока потребитель не отчитается, что он сообщение обработал. Если потребитель грохнется, очередь попробует выдать это же сообщение кому-нибудь ещё, а если никого нет, будет хранить сообщения у себя, пока кто-нибудь не подключится и не начнёт их забирать.

Answer (score -1):

Перезапускайте с помощью `forever restart bin/www`

Comment: Перезапустил, секунд 20 висела такая натпись:  Service Temporarily Unavailable The server is temporarily unable to service your request due to maintenance downtime or capacity problems. Please try again later. Apache/2.2.15 (CentOS) Server at boti-test-bn.dreamlex.com Port 80